# TextFieldParser into DataTable

Tags: database, vb.net, datatable, textfieldparser

I have a csv file read into a TextFieldParser.
Before I place the data rows into a DataTable, I want to add a couple of extra fields that are not in the csv.

This line writes all the csv data into the table ok -

```
        tempTable.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())
```

If I do something like this -

```
        tempTable.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields(), stationID, sMaxSpeedDecimal, sqlFormattedDate)
```

the Row.Add seems to treat all the Parser data as one field and then appends the new columns. Basically the parser data is lost to the database.
How can I add additional columns so the tempTable.Rows.Add includes all the parser data plus new column data in one write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either pass one array containing all the field values or else pass all the field values individually.  Because you are passing multiple arguments, it is assumed to be the latter and the array is treated as one field value.  You must either break up the array and pass each field individually, e.g.

```
Dim fields = parser.ReadFields()

tempTable.Rows.Add(fields(0), fields(1), stationID, sMaxSpeedDecimal, sqlFormattedDate)
```

or else combine the extra field values with the original array to create a new array, e.g.

```
Dim fields = parser.ReadFields().Concat({stationID, sMaxSpeedDecimal, sqlFormattedDate})

tempTable.Rows.Add(fields)
```

Comment: Sigh... thought that might be the case. I was hoping there was a clever way to do this as there is a ton of fields involved.

Comment: I would say that the second option is the "clever" way.  It would take eleven characters more than your original code, so what's the problem?

Comment: Yes you are right, 2nd is best and thankyou. 
Still giving me a problem though.   if I use   Dim fields = parser.ReadFields().Concat({stationID, sMaxSpeedDecimal.tostring, sqlFormattedDate})
tempTable.Rows.Add(fields)
I can see the field contents but the database is reflecting all nulls. If do it thus-  tempTable.Rows.Add(fields(0), fields(1), fields(2), fields(3), .... fields(12), fields(13), fields(14))
It works fine. I don't understand that.

Comment: That might be my fault. Try calling ToArray on fields and pass the result to Add.